# General solution of $\cos{4x}=\cos{2x}$

Tags: trigonometry

**My attempt:**
\begin{align}
\cos{4x}-\cos{2x} &=0 \\
\cos^2{2x}-\sin^2{2x}-\cos{2x} &=0 \\
\cos^2{2x}-1+\cos^2{2x}-\cos{2x} &=0 \\
\cos^2{2x}-\cos{2x}-1 &= 0 \\
(2\cos{2x}+1)(\cos{2x}-1) &= 0,
\end{align}
which leads to
$$\cos2x= -\frac{1}{2} \hspace{5mm} \text{or} \hspace{5mm} \cos2x=1,$$
$$2x=2n\pi\pm{2\pi\over3} \hspace{5mm} \text{or} \hspace{5mm} 2x=2n\pi$$
and
$$x=n\pi\pm{\pi\over3} \hspace{5mm} \text{  or  } \hspace{5mm} x=n\pi.$$

---

**Book Solution:** 
\begin{align}
\cos{4x}-\cos{2x} &=0 \\
-2\sin{3x}\sin{x} &=0 \\
\sin{3x}\sin{x} &=0.
\end{align}
$$\sin{3x}=0 \hspace{5mm} \text{or} \hspace{5mm} \sin{x}=0$$
$$3x=n\pi \hspace{5mm} \text{or} \hspace{5mm} x=n\pi$$
$$x=\frac{n\pi}{3} \hspace{5mm} \text{or} \hspace{5mm} x=n\pi$$

***My question is:*** How can there be two general solutions of a same equation Or did I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hint: any integer is either multiple of 3 or of the form $3n\pm 1$.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are  same answers.

I think it's better the following way.
$$4x=2x+2\pi k$$ or
$$4x=-2x+2\pi k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$, which gives else the same answer:
$$\left\{\frac{\pi k}{3}|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: $$4x=2n\pi \pm 2x$$ This directly gives $x=n\pi$ or $x={n\pi\over3}$ Thank you!

Comment: @mettled mike You are welcome! Also it's $\frac{n\pi}{3}$ only!

Comment: Why is $x=n\pi$ not the answer?

Comment: @mettledmike  Notice that when $k = 3n$, then $x = \frac{k\pi}{3} = n\pi$.  Therefore, every solution of the form $x = n\pi$ is also accounted for by stating that $x = \frac{k\pi}{3}$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don't understand. Help me out plz.

Comment: Consider the values $$\ldots, \color{blue}{-\frac{6\pi}{3}}, -\frac{5\pi}{3}, -\frac{4\pi}{3}, \color{blue}{-\frac{3\pi}{3}}, -\frac{2\pi}{3}, -\frac{\pi}{3}, \color{blue}{\frac{0\pi}{3}}, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}, \color{blue}{\frac{3\pi}{3}}, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{5\pi}{3}, \color{blue}{\frac{6\pi}{3}}, \ldots$$  Observe that the values marked in blue are $$\ldots, -2\pi, -\pi, 0, \pi, 2\pi, \ldots$$ that is, every number that can be expressed in the form $x = n\pi$ for some integer $n$ can also be expressed in the form $x = \frac{k\pi}{3}$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you so much! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is much more direct  if you think in terms of *congruences*:

\begin{align}
\cos 4x =\cos 2x&\iff 4x\equiv \pm2x \mod 2\pi\iff\begin{cases}2x\equiv 0\pmod{2\pi},\\ 6x\equiv 0\pmod{2\pi},\end{cases}\\
&\iff\begin{cases}x\equiv 0\pmod{\pi},\\[1ex] x\equiv 0\mod{\Bigl(\dfrac\pi3\Bigr)}.\end{cases}
\end{align}